# What does `onsubmit && !onsubmit()` do?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the code below, it looks like `onsubmit && !onsubmit()` is attempting to prevent accidentally submitting the form twice.

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
<img src="go.gif" width="33" height="19" border="0" />
</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
 { if(document.myform.onsubmit && !document.myform.onsubmit()) 
      { return; }
   document.myform.submit(); }
</script>
```

I don't understand how this works though; does `onsubmit` become non-null and `onsubmit()` always return false if `submit()` has been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's `submit` handler defined for this specific form, it's invoked; if it returns a falsy value, `submitform` function returns immediately - otherwise it submits the form.

From this description it looks like some kind of validation framework - if validation function is defined for a specific form, and its call returns `true` (meaning that form is filled correctly), the form is submitted.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Yes that looks very much like what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This code tests if `onsubmit` exists, and if so, calls it, and returns if the return value is `false`.

If the function is not defined, the second operator to `&&` is not evaluated, so the function is not called.

It is a short notation of the equivalent:

```
if (onsubmit) { // function exists
    if (!onsubmit()) { // function call returned false
        return; // cancel
    }
}
```

This allows the user to provide a custom submit handler that can call cancel the submission by returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It literally means: "if the form has an onsubmit handler and if this handler returns something falsy, return before it directly calls submit on the form, which won't call the onsubmit handler".